# How to reload environment variables in Python?

Tags: python, linux, jupyter-notebook

I set up a `systemctl` service (Jupyter) as part of a bootstrap for a Hadoop cluster. After bootstrap actions are completed, Hadoop is installed. During that step a number of environment variables are set - and these are vital for my service, Jupyter. Problem is, Jupyter does not know these environment variables, as it is started earlier in the process.

My question: how can I reload environment variables for my user? At the moment the user is running Jupyter, all env variables are known - I just need them loaded into the Python interpreter.

This fails inside notebook: `os.environ['JAVA_HOME']` but works fine in the interpreter (because `JAVA_HOME` was defined after Jupyter was started).

Comment: environment variables are local to a process when it starts and inherited from the parent process  I think you are not going to be able to set them from outside that process.   You can set them in that process but you would need to establish some way to pass them in.  (example put in file and have something on a thread periodically read and set them local to that process)

Comment: @LhasaDad Thanks for explaining, that's what I eventually did. I will be happy to accept that as an answer.

Comment: Thanks,  added it as an answer @Lukasz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Environment variables are local to a process when it starts and inherited from the parent process I think you are not going to be able to set them from outside that process. You can set them in that process but you would need to establish some way to pass them in. (example put in file and have something on a thread periodically read and set them local to that process)

Comment: Hi, LhasaDad, would you please give more details or steps how do you set the environment variable in Jupyter notebook? Thanks

Comment: os.environ['JAVA_HOME'] ="path" should work  that is setting the value will set it within the running process.

Comment: Ok, I see, that works for me. But just curious what is your working flow to load all your environment variables?  Do you put those lines to load environment variables i a file or what? Thanks

Comment: i was going on general knowledge of processes and environment inheritance.  I don't do a lot with Jupyter notebooks.  It was more from general Python programming that I provided my response.