# How to read the present environment variable

Tags: python, linux, environment-variables

I am having a python code where I want the current environment variable

I used os.environ() but it only shows the environment variable already set when the python code started. I need the program to print the environment variable which is set during its execution. My program may run for days

I need the latest env variable when the program tries to print it. I tried adding new environment variable through export command when needed temporarily or through bashrc

Is there a way to do

ps: Its a linux environment

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reload environment variables in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62514598/how-to-reload-environment-variables-in-python)

Comment: Yeah, you cannot reliably update the env of a running process from the outside. You may add some hook so you can pass an update into the process so it can update its own env. But probably you will need some other means  like a config file that your process reloads periodically or sth like that

Comment: To provide further context, the environment variables are stored in the memory of each individual process, making them separate for each process.

Comment: @user2390182 If any environment variable is set outside, where can we read them before using them in my running process? By hook what you mean exactly?